# Как сверстать сетку фотографий?

Tags: css

Добрый день, уважаемые советчики.

Есть сетка изображений. Не могу ее сверстать правильно, может быть кто-нибудь подскажет как подойти к задаче? Вот что получается сейчас: http://codepen.io/shugich/pen/MejMQw

```css
section {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div {
  width: 490px;
  height: 450px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Helvetice', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.small {
  height: 215px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="small">2</div>
  <div class="small">3</div>
  <div class="small">4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div class="small">8</div>
  <div class="small">9</div>
  <div class="small">10</div>
</section>
```

[image: Сетка]

Comment: Знаю про Masonry, но хотелось бы сделать это без использования js.

Comment: Там не нужно подгонять для каждого. Есть всего два размера: 490×450 пикселей и 490×215 пикселей. Отступ между изображениями 20 пикселей как сбоку, так и снизу.

Comment: Через колонки тоже подход знаю, но он не подходит потому что там такой порядок изображений не сохраняется, а это важно.

Comment: Это не то. Там сетка по-другому строится.

Comment: @DmitryShishkin, разметка постоянная? или количество и порядок могут меняться?

Comment: @Grundy разметка постоянная и меняться не будет. Вниз может добавится еще сколько-то фотографий, но они всегда должны вставить по этой сетке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я нашел решение. Оно не совсем соответствует задаче потому что четвертая и пятая картинки поменялись местами, но это меня тоже устраивает. Вот решение: http://codepen.io/shugich/pen/qNazGx

Выражение 10n+4 и 10n+7 я использую потому что к этому потоку могут добавляться еще изображения. С таким подходом они всегда будут вставить по этой сетке.

```css
section {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 -10px -20px;
}
.item {
  width: 490px;
  height: 450px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Helvetice', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 10px 20px;
  float: left;
}
.small {
  height: 215px;
}
.item:nth-child(10n + 4),
.item:nth-child(10n + 7) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item small">2</div>
    <div class="item small">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item small">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item small">8</div>
    <div class="item small">9</div>
    <div class="item small">10</div>
  </div>
</section>
```